# How to have "empty" for x509's nameConstraints extension subtree?

Tags: openssl

I am signing x509 certificates that should only be used for CN under a specific domain, not for any IP/email/UPN.

the [rfc5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10) says that passing `empty` to a permitted value will allow all of those class, while to a excluded class will deny all of those class.

> initial-permitted-subtrees, which indicates for each name type (e.g., X.500 distinguished names, email addresses, or IP addresses) a set of subtrees within which all subject names in every certificate in the certification path MUST fall. The initial-permitted-subtrees input includes a set for each name type.  For each name type, the set may consist of a single subtree that includes all names of that name type or one or more subtrees that each specifies a subset of the names of that name type, or the set may be empty.  If the set for a name type is empty, then the certification path will be considered invalid if any certificate in the certification path includes a name of that name type.
>
> --- rfc5280  6.1.1(h)

First i learned there's no UPN class for this extension, so right from the start i already know this won't do. Continuing then for Email and IP.

I cannot find how to specify `empty` on [openssl extension config file](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html) nor on general [openssl config files](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/config.html). There is a single mention of a special case for one option that accepts `EMPTY`. but using both `EMPTY` or `empty` (as the powershell tools accept) results in a literal string on my certs for email, and Failure for IP.

```
$ grep namedConstraints cert.cfg
nameConstraints=permitted;DNS:01.org, excluded;IP:empty, excluded;email:empty
$ openssl x509 ... -extfile my-root-ca-br.cfg
40F784080B7F0000:error:11000076:X509 V3 routines:a2i_GENERAL_NAME:bad ip address:crypto/x509/v3_san.c:556:value=empty
40F784080B7F0000:error:11000080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf_int:error in extension:crypto/x509/v3_conf.c:48:section=...

$ grep namedConstraints cert2.cfg
nameConstraints=permitted;DNS:01.org, excluded;email:EMPTY
$ openssl x509 ... -extfile my-root-ca-br.cfg
$ openssl x509 -in crt -text
...
               Excluded:
                  email:EMPTY
...

$ grep namedConstraints cert2.cfg
nameConstraints=permitted;DNS:01.org, excluded;email:empty
$ openssl x509 ... -extfile my-root-ca-br.cfg
$ openssl x509 -in crt -text
...
               Excluded:
                  email:empty
...
```

...i don't think that looks right.

Edit:
alternatively, how to specify ALL email/ips?

```
nameConstraints=critical,permitted... excluded;email:., excluded;IP:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, excluded;IP:::/::
...

                Excluded:
                  email:.
                  IP:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
                  IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
```

is this it?

Comment: Your link is to 4.2.1.10 (the extension) but your quote is from 6.1.1 (the inputs to the validation algorithm); these are completely different things. The initial sets can be empty but the extension sets cannot; see the ASN.1. The 'exclude all' cases you show are definitely correct for v4 and v6 addrs; email looks good but I would have to test to be sure and you're already doing that.

Comment: section 4.2.1.10 says "Restrictions are defined in terms of permitted or excluded name subtrees". I did not find any other definition of subtree other than 6.1.1, is there other i should look?

Comment: The ASN.1 is as the end of 4.2.1.10, at the bottom of page 42 and top of page 43. Plus the prose statement at the end of the same paragraph you quoted, "either the permittedSubtrees field or the excludedSubtrees field MUST be present"; this expresses a constraint additional to the ASN.1 definition.